# after selected dropdownlist option display hidden textbox

Tags: javascript, jquery

i have an problem on choosing dropdownlist it giving an null while selected it

Here is the code:

```
    <asp:GridView ID="gridview1" runat="server" AllowPaging="false"  Width="99%" >

    <asp:BoundField DataField="NAME" HeaderText ="Name" HtmlEncode="false"/>

    <asp:BoundField DataField="ID " HeaderText ="ID " HtmlEncode="false"/>

      <asp:TemplateField HeaderText ="Location">
      <ItemTemplate>

     <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlfruitAgent" runat="server" onchange="Store_Location_onChange(this)" />
     <asp:TextBox ID="StoreLocation" runat="server" TextMode="MultiLine" Rows="2" style="width:97%;display:none" />
      </ItemTemplate>
       </asp:TemplateField>
```

javascript:

```
function Store_Location_onChange(objThis) {
    if (objThis.value == "0") {

        document.getElementById("StoreLocation").style.display = "";
    }
    else {
        document.getElementById("StoreLocation").value = "";
        document.getElementById("StoreLocation").style.display = "none";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you're passing `this` as a reference of an object, you can do like this

```
function Store_Location_onChange(objThis) {
    if (objThis.value == "0") {
        objThis.nextElementSibling.style.display = "";
    }
    else {
        objThis.nextElementSibling.value = "";
        objThis.nextElementSibling.style.display = "none";
    }
}
```

OR Other way around is

```
function Store_Location_onChange(objThis) {
    if (objThis.value == "0") {
        document.getElementById("<%= StoreLocation.ClientID %>").style.display = "";
    }
    else {
        documentgetElementById("<%= StoreLocation.ClientID %>").value = "";
        document.getElementById("<%= StoreLocation.ClientID %>").style.display = "none";
    }
}
```

hope this helps!

Comment: it has an error  JavaScript runtime error:Unable to set defination or Null reference attribute value
while i try to select the dropdownlist

Comment: console this line `--> objThis.nextElementSibling` and see what is returns!

Comment: dropdownlist is generate by code behind is an sql query

Comment: didn't have any log when choosing the dropdownlist it keep on showing this error message 0x800a138f JavaScript runtime error:Unable to set defination or Null reference attribute value while i try to select the dropdownlist

Comment: i found the problem adding ClientIDMode="Static" because the textbox is generate unreable numberic causing null problem, how to make the textbox appear when needed i try to set .style.display = "true" it will causing null again...

Comment: OK problem solve. Thank you for your help @Dhaval Marthak is my sql script problem causing when is 0 doesn't show the textbox .